# How to conditionally format a cell based on time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm making a sheet and trying to highlight cells based on time but not sure how to do that.

[image: check the picture]

so the time in sheet represents number of transactions we have per hour, so I want the sheet dynamically highlight the current hour to to point at number of transactions we have (for that hour), regardless of the minutes and seconds.

so basically

if the time on cell == current time (regardless of minutes and seconds)
return TRUE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
=HOUR(A1)=HOUR(NOW())
```

Where A1 is the first cell that contains a time. Note the applies to range.

[image]

Comment: thank you, that worked